# Knockout append to class binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-validate, wijmo

I'm using Knockout, wijmo, and Jquery Validation. As part of the requirement for jquery validation to correctly work one must assign the class required. When this is done using knockout it overrides the class assigned by wijmo. Hence dropping any fancy css along with it. I would like to append required to the class.

Knockout is using templates to assign the correct input from the database.

```
<script type="text/html" id="WijmoTextAreaControl">
    <textarea  rows="5" data-bind="wijtextbox: {}, value: Value, wijtooltip: {title: 'Tooltip should be linked to an observable'}, attr: {placeholder: DatabaseName.PlaceholdText, class: DatabaseName.class}" />
</script>
```

the class: binding replaces the wijmo class with required. Is there anyway to append the class information to the binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `css` binding instead of `attr` for assigninn class.

```
<textarea  rows="5" data-bind="wijtextbox: {}, value: Value, wijtooltip: {title: 'Tooltip should be linked to an observable'}, attr: {placeholder: DatabaseName.PlaceholdText}, css: {'Your class name': true}" />
```

Comment: <textarea  rows="5" data-bind="wijtextbox: {}, value: Value, wijtooltip: {title: 'Tooltip should be linked to an observable'}, attr: {placeholder: DatabaseName.PlaceholdText}, css: {'required': DatabaseName.class}"" />